# How to create a linear fractional distribution as a custom discrete probability distribution?

Tags: python, scipy, scipy.stats

I defined the following custom probability distribution:

```
import scipy.stats as st

# parameters
a = 3 / 16
b = 1

class linear_fractional(st.rv_discrete):
    def _pdf(self, n):
        if (n == 0):
            return (a + b - 1) / (a + b)
        else:
            return (a * b ** (n - 1)) / (a + b) ** (n + 1)

LF = linear_fractional()
LF.rvs()
```

When I let my script run I get a lengthy error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/thoma/PycharmProjects/Host_Parasite_Coevolution/Asymptotics.py", line 17, in <module> LF.rvs()
File "C:\Users\thoma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py", line 2969, in rvs
    return super(rv_discrete, self).rvs(*args, **kwargs)

...

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

If I do `LF.mean()` instead, I get

```
Fatal Python error: Cannot recover from stack overflow.
```

Does anyone know why that is and how I could solve this issue? Do I have to define an upper bound on my probability distribution?

Comment: Win 10, x64, Python 3.7, Spyder 3.3.6, IPython 7.13.0 code runs with no errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the examples given at [the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_discrete.html) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23276631/scipy-generating-custom-random-variable-from-pmf), the approach needs some modification. Importantly, as is it a discrete distribution, `_pmf` should be used instead of `_pdf`. Also, the `_pmf` will get called by numpy-style arrays for `n`, for which `n == 0` works quite differently.

As `(a * b ** (n - 1)) / (a + b) ** (n + 1)` is equal to `(a + b - 1) / (a + b)` when `n == 0`, we can just use that first expression for all `n`. However, numpy generates an error when `b` is an integer and `n = -1`. Multiplying `b` with `1.0` changes it to a float for which numpy doesn't give such error. If the same parameters `a` and `b` are used multiple times, a frozen distribution could be generated.

Here is an example, which creates a histogram of the generated samples, and compares it with the `pmf`.

```
import scipy.stats as st
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

class linear_fractional(st.rv_discrete):
    def _pmf(self, n, a, b):
        return (a * (1.0 * b) ** (n - 1)) / (a + b) ** (n + 1)

# parameters
a = 3 / 16
b = 1

LF = linear_fractional()

N = 10000
plt.hist(LF.rvs(a, b, size=N), bins=np.arange(-0.5, 50), ec='w', label='histogram of samples')
plt.plot(LF.pmf(np.arange(50), a, b) * N, 'ro', label='probability mass function (scaled)')
plt.legend(title=f'$a={a}; b={b}$')
plt.autoscale(enable=True, axis='x', tight=True)
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting histogram]

`LF.mean(a, b)` outputs `5.33333333333286`

A scatter plot is an alternative way to illustrate samples from a distribution:

```py
plt.scatter(np.random.uniform(0, 1, N), LF.rvs(a, b, size=N), marker=',', alpha=0.2, lw=0, s=1, color='crimson')
```

[image: scatter plot]

PS: When `b=1`, the formula for this distribution is equal to the [geometric distribution](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.geometric.html) with `p = a/(a+1)` and subtracting 1. This is much faster as it is completely calculated inside numpy.

```
samples = np.random.geometric(a/(a+1), size=1000) - 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Great answer!